# Truncate and Load a Kusto table instead of a Materialized view so that it can be used for continous export

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

We have a scenario where some reference data is getting ingested in a Kusto table (~1000 rows).

To handle data duplication due to daily data load (as Kusto does always append), we have created a Materialized view(MV) on top of the table to summarize the data and get the latest data based on ingestion_time(), so that querying the MV will always result in latest updated reference data.

Our next ask is to export this formatted data in a storage container using Kusto continuous data export ([please refer MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/continuous-data-export)), however, it seems we can't use Materialized view to set up a continuous export.

So looking at options, is there any way we can create a truncate load table instead of a Materialized View in kusto, so that we don't have a duplicate record in the table and it can be used to do continuous export.

```
.create async materialized-view with (backfill=true) products_vw on table products
    {
    products
    | extend d=parse_json(record)
    | extend
        createdBy=tostring(d.createdBy),
        createdDate = tostring(d.createdDate),
        product_id=tostring(d.id),
        product_name=tostring(d.name),
        ingest_time=ingestion_time()
    | project
        ingest_time,
        createdBy,
        createdDate,
        product_id,
        product_name
    | summarize arg_max(ingest_time, *) by product_id
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Azure logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/tools/logicapps) or [Microsoft flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/flow) to run the applicable [export command to an external table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/export-data-to-an-external-table) backed by Azure storage on any given time interval. The query can simply refer to the materialized view, for example:

```
.export to table ExternalBlob <| Your_MV
```

Comment: Thank you Avnera! That would work and would be an option however, I wanted to know if we can somehow work out in Kusto without integrating with other Azure tools.  If not, I believe will have to schedule it via the logic app.